# Python - error message when not using private member

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, runtime-error, private-members

I get an error when i run the following:

```
class Product:
def __init__(self, price):
    self.setprice(price)
def getprice(self):
    return self.price
def setprice(self, value):
    if value < 0:
        raise ValueError("Price cannot be negative")
    self.price = value
price = property(getprice, setprice)
```

x = Product(23)
print(x.price)

The error is below:

`File "c:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\PYTHON\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 9, in setprice self.price = value [Previous line repeated 993 more times] File "c:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\PYTHON\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 7, in setprice if value < 0: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

However when i make the price a private member, it runs ok :

```
class Product:
def __init__(self, price):
    self.setprice(price)
def getprice(self):
    return self.__price
def setprice(self, value):
    if value < 0:
        raise ValueError("Price cannot be negative")
    self.__price = value
price = property(getprice, setprice)
```

x = Product(23)
print(x.price)

Can anyone tell me why we get this error???? Why do we need to make price private in the setprice method?

Comment: Properly format your question.. Inappropriate indentation.

Comment: sorry...newbie here.. just started learning programming.. will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to define properties with `property` is:

```py
class Product
    def __init__(self, price):
        self.price = price
    @property
    def price(self):
        return self._price
    @price.setter
    def price(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Price can't be negative.")
        self._price = value
```

Then you can use it as you would expect:

```
>>> p = Product(3)
>>> p.price
3
>>> p.price = -1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in price
ValueError: Price can't be negative.
>>> p.price
3
>>> p.price = 4
>>> p.price
4
>>>
```

---

Your error stems from the fact that when you define `self.price = ...`, you actually call the setter once again, thus recurring over and over again, until the max depth recursion limit is reached. When you set `self._price` instead, you are not using the setter, but doing a regular assignment instead.

Comment: Thanks... the setter being called again by self.price explains why we get the error. However i still cannot figure out how, by making the price protected in self._price, it becomes a regular assignment.